# How does JVM Classfile verifier works?

Tags: java, jvm

How does JVM classfile verifier perform class verification ?

Could anyone please tell me the steps ?

Comment: Could you accept one of the answers below please :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are four passes:

1. **Basic Format Check** (When Class is Loaded) - (magic number, check constant pool).
2. **Additional Verification** (When Linking) - Check final modifiers, check for direct subclasses, valid fields, check constant pool.
3. **Bytecode Verification** (When Linking) - Check the code array - operand stack is ok, local variables, correct method invocation, field assignment etc...
4. **Virtual Pass** (Code Invoked) - ensure referenced classes/methods exist and have the correct descriptors.

Full gory details here, see section 4.9.1 The Verification Process

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html

Answer (score 3):

See section 4.9 of the [VM Spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#88597).  The process is spelled out in detail.